# javascript return the checking value if condition matches, otherwise another value

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

So I was wondering if there was some inbuilt method that was similar to the ternary operator but would return the left value of a truthy check, while returning the right if falsey.

Here's what I plan to do if there isn't (and to clarify what I mean)

```js
function myTernary(leftValue, operator, condition, rightValue) {
  let expression = `${leftValue} ${operator} ${condition}`
  let result = eval('('+expression+')')
  return result ? leftValue : rightValue
}

// leftValue is returned if the condition is truthy, otherwise rightValue

console.log(myTernary(1 + 2 + 3 + 4, "<", 12, 12))
```

`eval` will be executed on client side so... it should be fine right, since clients can arbitrarily open their web console and just input anything they want anyway.

Comment: `leftValue === condition ? leftValue : rightValue` is all that does...

Comment: Are you asking for `then ? condition : otherwise`? No, that's not possible, just reorder the operands.

Comment: Your example might be clearer if you didn't use `eval`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know you can do that. I just have a pretty big expression so I just wanted to see if I could save space. I have something like `x + z + e + g < 12` and I just want to return the total of x, z, ,e ,g if they are less than 12, otherwise right side, I could also move that totalling outside to another variable and then return that, but it was just a curious question.

Comment: `var q = x + z + e + g; return q < 12 ? q : rightValue`

Comment: I used to be tempted to ask questions like this until I understood that code clarity is more important than code brevity.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts true enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `||` operator...

```js
console.log(1!=2||5)
console.log(1==2||5)
```

Comment: well I don't want true or false, I want the ACTUAL value. I'll change the example so it's actually a bit clearer.